# ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install -- when running: pip install --upgrade --no-binary hdbscan

Tags: python, pip, hdbscan

I am trying to install hdbscan in my PC which runs Windows 10 and has installed Python 3.6.

My first attempt failed:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install hdbscan --user
Collecting hdbscan
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/7c/1401ec61b0e7392287e045b6913206cfff050b65d869c19f7ec0f5626487/hdbscan-0.8.22.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.17 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (0.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.27 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (0.29.10)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.9 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.2.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: hdbscan
  Building wheel for hdbscan (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\python.exe' 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8ir950og'
       cwd: C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxifwoph\hdbscan
  Complete output (67 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\hdbscan_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\plots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\prediction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\robust_single_linkage_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\validity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_hdbscan.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_rsl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hdbscan\tests
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 141, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n2heecpm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 209, in build_wheel
      wheel_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n2heecpm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 194, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n2heecpm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 237, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n2heecpm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 96, in <module>
      setup(**configuration)
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n2heecpm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n2heecpm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 26, in run
      build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n2heecpm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
      _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
      force=self.force)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
      return klass(None, dry_run, force)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 285, in __init__
      CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 129, in __init__
      if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
  TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
  Running setup.py clean for hdbscan
Failed to build hdbscan
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Do you understand why the system could not build the wheels for hdbscan?

Is there something I can do about it? What are the alternatives at this point?

I tried to install the hdbscan without the binaries but again failed:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --upgrade --no-binary hdbscan
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

---

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip list outdated
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- ---------------------
matplotlib                         2.2.2
scipy                              1.1.0
numpy                              1.14.3
absl-py                            0.7.1
alabaster                          0.7.10
anaconda-client                    1.6.14
anaconda-navigator                 1.8.7
anaconda-project                   0.8.2
arviz                              0.4.1
asn1crypto                         0.24.0
aspy.yaml                          1.2.0
astor                              0.7.1
astroid                            1.6.3
astropy                            3.0.2
astunparse                         1.6.2
attrs                              18.1.0
autograd                           1.2
Babel                              2.5.3
backcall                           0.1.0
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
beautifulsoup4                     4.6.0
bitarray                           0.8.1
bkcharts                           0.2
blaze                              0.11.3
bleach                             1.5.0
blis                               0.2.4
bokeh                              0.12.16
boto                               2.48.0
boto3                              1.9.130
botocore                           1.12.130
Bottleneck                         1.2.1
brewer2mpl                         1.4.1
bs4                                0.0.1
bz2file                            0.98
certifi                            2018.4.16
cffi                               1.11.5
cfgv                               1.6.0
cftime                             1.0.3.4
chardet                            3.0.4
click                              6.7
cloudpickle                        1.2.1
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.3.9
colour                             0.1.5
comtypes                           1.1.4
conda                              4.6.8
conda-build                        3.10.5
conda-verify                       2.0.0
contextlib2                        0.5.5
convertdate                        2.1.3
cryptography                       2.2.2
cycler                             0.10.0
cymem                              2.0.2
Cython                             0.29.10
cytoolz                            0.9.0.1
d2l                                0.9.2
dask                               0.17.5
datashape                          0.5.4
decorator                          4.3.0
dill                               0.3.0
distributed                        1.21.8
Django                             2.2.2
dltk                               0.2.1
docutils                           0.14
el-core-news-md                    2.1.0
el-core-news-sm                    2.1.0
embedder                           0.1
en-core-web-md                     2.1.0
entrypoints                        0.2.3
ephem                              3.7.6.0
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.0.2
fastdtw                            0.3.2
fasttext                           0.8.3
fbprophet                          0.1.post1
filelock                           3.0.4
fix-yahoo-finance                  0.0.22
Flask                              1.0.2
Flask-Cors                         3.0.4
future                             0.17.1
gast                               0.2.2
gensim                             3.7.1
geojson                            2.4.1
gevent                             1.3.0
ggplot                             0.11.5
glob2                              0.6
google-pasta                       0.1.4
googleapis-common-protos           1.6.0
graphviz                           0.8.4
greenlet                           0.4.13
grpcio                             1.19.0
gym                                0.14.0
h5py                               2.7.1
heapdict                           1.0.0
hmmlearn                           0.2.2
holidays                           0.9.10
html5lib                           0.9999999
hyperopt                           0.1.1
identify                           1.4.1
idna                               2.6
image                              1.5.27
imageio                            2.3.0
imagesize                          1.0.0
importlib-metadata                 0.9
importlib-resources                1.0.2
inflection                         0.3.1
ipykernel                          4.8.2
ipython                            6.4.0
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.2.1
isort                              4.3.4
iterative-stratification           0.1.6
itsdangerous                       0.24
jdcal                              1.4
jedi                               0.12.0
Jinja2                             2.10
jmespath                           0.9.4
joblib                             0.13.2
json-tricks                        3.12.2
jsonschema                         2.6.0
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     5.2.3
jupyter-console                    5.2.0
jupyter-contrib-core               0.3.3
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions       0.5.1
jupyter-core                       4.4.0
jupyter-highlight-selected-word    0.2.0
jupyter-latex-envs                 1.4.6
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator  0.4.1
jupyterlab                         0.32.1
jupyterlab-launcher                0.10.5
Keras                              2.2.5
Keras-Applications                 1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing                1.1.0
keras-rl                           0.4.2
kiwisolver                         1.0.1
lazy-object-proxy                  1.3.1
llvmlite                           0.23.1
locket                             0.2.0
lunardate                          0.2.0
lxml                               4.4.1
Markdown                           3.1
MarkupSafe                         1.0
matplotlib                         3.1.1
mccabe                             0.6.1
menuinst                           1.4.14
mistune                            0.8.3
mkl-fft                            1.0.0
mkl-random                         1.0.1
mock                               2.0.0
more-itertools                     4.1.0
mpld3                              0.3
mpmath                             1.0.0
msgpack                            0.6.1
msgpack-python                     0.5.6
multipledispatch                   0.5.0
multitasking                       0.0.7
murmurhash                         1.0.2
mxnet-cu101                        1.5.0
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbconvert                          5.3.1
nbformat                           4.4.0
netCDF4                            1.5.1.2
networkx                           2.1
neuralcoref                        4.0
nltk                               3.3
NNI                                0.1.0
nodeenv                            1.3.3
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           5.5.0
numba                              0.38.0
numexpr                            2.6.5
numpy                              1.17.2
numpydoc                           0.8.0
odo                                0.5.1
olefile                            0.45.1
opencv-python                      4.1.1.26
openpyxl                           2.5.3
packaging                          17.1
pandas                             0.24.2
pandas-datareader                  0.7.0
pandocfilters                      1.4.2
parso                              0.2.0
partd                              0.3.8
path.py                            11.0.1
pathlib2                           2.3.2
patsy                              0.5.0
pbr                                5.1.3
pep8                               1.7.1
pickleshare                        0.7.4
Pillow                             5.1.0
pip                                19.2.3
pixiedust                          1.1.13
pkginfo                            1.4.2
plac                               0.9.6
plotly                             4.0.0
pluggy                             0.6.0
ply                                3.11
pmdarima                           1.2.1
pre-commit                         1.15.1
preshed                            2.0.1
promise                            2.2.1
prompt-toolkit                     1.0.15
protobuf                           3.7.1
psutil                             5.4.5
py                                 1.5.3
py-translate                       1.0.3
pybind11                           2.2.4
pycodestyle                        2.4.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.18
pycrypto                           2.6.1
pycurl                             7.43.0.1
pydot                              1.4.1
pydotplus                          2.0.2
pyflakes                           1.6.0
pyglet                             1.3.2
Pygments                           2.2.0
pylint                             1.8.4
pymongo                            3.7.1
pyodbc                             4.0.23
pyOpenSSL                          18.0.0
pyparsing                          2.2.0
PyProcessMacro                     1.0.0
pyreadstat                         0.2.1
PySocks                            1.6.8
pystan                             2.19.0.0
pytest                             3.5.1
pytest-arraydiff                   0.2
pytest-astropy                     0.3.0
pytest-doctestplus                 0.1.3
pytest-openfiles                   0.3.0
pytest-remotedata                  0.2.1
python-dateutil                    2.7.3
pytz                               2018.4
PyWavelets                         0.5.2
pywin32                            223
pywinpty                           0.5.1
PyYAML                             3.12
pyzmq                              17.0.0
QtAwesome                          0.4.4
qtconsole                          4.3.1
QtPy                               1.4.1
Quandl                             3.4.6
regex                              2019.8.19
requests                           2.22.0
retrying                           1.3.3
rope                               0.10.7
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.35
s3transfer                         0.2.0
sacremoses                         0.0.34
scikit-image                       0.15.0
scikit-learn                       0.19.1
scipy                              1.2.2
seaborn                            0.9.0
sec-edgar-downloader               2.2.1
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
sentencepiece                      0.1.83
setuptools                         41.2.0
setuptools-git                     1.2
shap                               0.30.1
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
SimpleITK                          1.2.2
simplejson                         3.16.0
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
six                                1.11.0
smart-open                         1.8.0
snowballstemmer                    1.2.1
sortedcollections                  0.6.1
sortedcontainers                   1.5.10
spacy                              2.1.3
Sphinx                             1.7.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.0.1
spyder                             3.2.8
SQLAlchemy                         1.2.7
sqlparse                           0.3.0
srsly                              0.0.5
statsmodels                        0.9.0
sympy                              1.1.1
tables                             3.4.3
tb-nightly                         1.14.0a20190301
tblib                              1.3.2
tensorboard                        2.0.0
tensorflow                         2.0.0a0
tensorflow-datasets                1.2.0
tensorflow-estimator               1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu                     1.13.1
tensorflow-metadata                0.14.0
tensorflow-probability             0.6.0
termcolor                          1.1.0
terminado                          0.8.1
testpath                           0.3.1
tf-estimator-nightly               1.14.0.dev2019030115
tfds-nightly                       1.2.0.dev201909050105
Theano                             1.0.4
thinc                              7.0.4
toml                               0.10.0
toolz                              0.9.0
torch                              1.0.1
tornado                            5.0.2
tox                                3.8.6
tqdm                               4.31.1
tradingeconomics                   0.2.953
traitlets                          4.3.2
transformers                       2.0.0
translate                          3.5.0
tsfresh                            0.11.2
tushare                            1.2.39
typing                             3.6.4
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
urllib3                            1.22
virtualenv                         16.4.3
wasabi                             0.2.1
wcwidth                            0.1.7
webencodings                       0.5.1
websocket-client                   0.56.0
Werkzeug                           0.14.1
wheel                              0.31.1
widgetsnbextension                 3.2.1
win-inet-pton                      1.0.1
win-unicode-console                0.5
wincertstore                       0.2
wrapt                              1.10.11
xarray                             0.12.3
xgboost                            0.82
xlrd                               1.1.0
XlsxWriter                         1.0.4
xlwings                            0.11.8
xlwt                               1.3.0
yahoo-finance                      1.4.0
yahoofinancials                    1.5
yfinance                           0.1.45
zict                               0.1.3
zipp                               0.3.3
```

Comment: First things that I would do in your place: a) fresh virtualevn/pipenv environment, if it still breaks: b) fresh environvenment with  **non-anaconda** python, c) try in virtual machine. First step is to verify that package combination is possible in principle.

Comment: Also: did you check `pip list --outdated`? Don't you see something suspicious?

Comment: I run the pip list --outdated and you can see the output.

Comment: Oh-ho! I would certainly try to update this installation but in case something go wrong - I recomend to create fresh clean environment. E.g. `pipenv --python 3.7` in new directory. And why you use python 3.6? Is it intended?

Comment: This is the version I installed.  I am not familiar with setting up and using environment.  Probably I should learn more.  So I am not sure I follow you.  But I can try :)

Comment: Be aware that anaconda is very specific distribution (think about it like racing car). Probably you need to update thru `conda` not `pip`. E.g. `conda update --all` and `conda install hdbscan`

Comment: I can not run conda.  I am getting an error message.  (base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install hdbscan
\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200499/discussion-between-alex-yu-and-user8270077).

Comment: Here is some advice that will be helpful. It is as much for readers considering helping as it is for you. (1) you are probably asking too many questions. Eight posts in two days means that you are not waiting for answers on one thing before jumping to the next thing. This would further indicate to me that you are not doing the necessary research. (2) You are adding chatty material about appreciating help, even though many editors have removed this from your prior posts. Technical writing is an expectation here. Meta references are available on request.

Answer (score 3):

The `--no-binary` option is more complicated than it appears. It requires a *separate* list of packages for which you don't want the binary to be used:

```
--no-binary <format_control>
       Do not use binary packages. Can be supplied multiple times, and
       each time adds to the existing value. Accepts either :all: to
       disable all binary packages, :none: to empty the set, or one
       or more package names with commas between them. Note that some
       packages are tricky to compile and may fail to install when this
       option is used on them.
```

So you probably want

```
> pip install --upgrade --no-binary hdbscan hdbscan
```

Comment: Installing collected packages: hdbscan
  Running setup.py install for hdbscan ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered this error while installing Tensorflow Object Detection API.

After the last instruction, I forgot to put a full stop at the end of the code. Please check to see if anything is missing after the word install.

```
# Install the Object Detection API
%%bash
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install . (. dot is necessary)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue using Ubuntu 18 and Python3.6.
I resolved it installing the below packages:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3 python-dev python3-dev \
     build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
     python-pip
```

and installing the requirement using --no-binary option

I know it is not a copy-paste solution for a windows user but maybe you are missing some dev libs as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes-- installing HDBSCAN into Windows machine is a bit tricky since it has dependencies with the build tools. Seems like you are installing it within the Anaconda environment, use the following command which solved the problem for me.

```
conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan
```